# Returning one object that's built with nested promises

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise

I'm struggling to wrap my head around a nested promise layout where one one object is returned at the end of it. My current code is as follows:

router

```
router.get(`/${config.version}/event/:id?`, function (req, res, next) {
    var event = new Event(req, res, next);
    event.getInfo(req.params.id).then((info) => {
        res.send(info);
    });
});
```

function

```
getInfo(id) {
    db.main('events').where('id', id).select()
    .then((result) => {
        if(result.length > 0) {
            var event = result[0];

            //regular functions
            event.status = this.getStatus(id);
            event.content = this.getContent(id);
            event.price = this.getPrice(id);

            //promise functions
            var users = this.getUsers(id);
            var hosts = this.getHosts(id);

            Promise.all([users, hosts]).then(values => {
                event.users = values[0];
                event.hosts = values[1];

                //return whole event object to router
                return event;
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                return {
                    result: 'error',
                    error: err
                };
            });

        } else {
            return {
                    result: 'error',
                    error: "Event does not exist"
                };
        }
    }).catch((e) => {
        return {
                    result: 'error',
                    error: "Could not retrieve event info"
                };
    });
}
```

As you can see, the router initiates a call to get info about an event. The function then does a database call and gets some event data. Thereafter  I need to get the users and hosts of the event from a different table, append that info to the event object as well and then return the whole object to the router to be sent to the client.

When I do this I get an error because I'm not returning a promise from the getInfo function, but I'm not sure how or which promise I'm supposed to return.

I'd appreciate some help with this. Thanks

Comment: I ran into just this issue last night and am curious what the best practices are (or if there's already an answer).

Comment: @ssube it seems the easiest approach is to wrap your code with a promise, then simply call resolve() once you have all the data gathered. In my case I called the resolve() for the wrapper promise from within the Promise.all(...).then(...), much like you see in Ahmed's answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `.then` means that you are returning a promise.

```
function getInfo(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    resolve('yay!');
  })
}
getInfo().then(function(result) { //result = yay! });
```

to make your code work, simply replace all the returns with resolves, the errors with rejects, and wrap the whole thing with a `return new Promise` as i did.

```js
getInfo(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.main('events').where('id', id).select()
      .then((result) => {
        if (result.length > 0) {
          var event = result[0];

          //regular functions
          event.status = this.getStatus(id);
          event.content = this.getContent(id);
          event.price = this.getPrice(id);

          //promise functions
          var users = this.getUsers(id);
          var hosts = this.getHosts(id);

          Promise.all([users, hosts]).then(values => {
              event.users = values[0];
              event.hosts = values[1];

              //return whole event object to router
              resolve(event);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
              reject({
                result: 'error',
                error: err
              });
            });

        } else {
          reject({
            result: 'error',
            error: "Event does not exist"
          });
        }
      }).catch((e) => {
        reject({
          result: 'error',
          error: "Could not retrieve event info"
        });
      });
  });
}
```

Comment: If `db.main().select().then()` is already a promise, then it is an anti-pattern to wrap a promise in another one when you already have one that you can just return.  The code would also be a lot simpler.

Comment: how can we know for sure that it is a promise? or if it has `.then` then sure it returns a promise right?

Comment: You read the doc for the database you're using or look at the code to find out if actually has promise-like behavior.  Most DBs now-a-days have a promise option built in because it's a so much better way to use them.  A `.then()` implies a promise, but there are some poor imitations that aren't promise compliant so it's worth finding out if they're real promises.

Comment: @AhmadBamieh if you're not sure it's a real promise, but it is a thenable, then wrap it in `Promise.resolve()`

Comment: @Kovensky can you suggest an edit to my code to show me how exactly? i understand what you mean but i'm not sure how it works.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap your async code in Promise like this:

```
getInfo(id) {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    db.main('events').where('id', id).select()
    .then((result) => {
       //...
       resolve(/* result */)
       // OR
       reject(/* Error */)
  })
}
```

Note: Use `resolve` and `reject` instead `return`

Answer (score 0):

It's a combination of several things, but the main one is that you are never returning anything from `getInfo`, so your router handler is calling `.then` on `undefined`.

Do not call `.catch` (without `throw`ing inside it) on `Promise`s you intend to return for a caller to consume. This makes it not possible to use `.catch`, because you recovered the `Promise` chain into a resolved one.

Whatever you return inside a `.then` will be merged into the promise chain, so it's not actually a "Promise that resolves with a Promise". Your whole code could be replaced with:

```js
getInfo (id) {
    return db.main('events').where('id', id).select()
    .then(result => {
        if (result.length == 0) {
            // you can also just throw your error object thing,
            // but standard Error are generally the convention
            throw new Error('Event does not exist')
        }

        const [event] = result

        event.status = this.getStatus(id)
        event.content = this.getContent(id)
        event.price = this.getPrice(id)

        return Promise.all([this.getUsers(id), this.getHosts(id)])
        .then(([users, hosts]) => {
            event.users = users
            event.hosts = hosts

            // this is the only value that
            // this.getInfo(id).then(value => {/* ... */}) will see
            return event
        }
    })
}
```